# Does a correlation coefficient, such that ||=1, between two random variables imply that the covariance matrix is not invertible?

Tags: self-study, correlation, covariance, covariance-matrix

Assume that (1,2) is a random vector with (1)<∞,(2)<∞. Which of the following statements imply that the covariance matrix of (1,2) is not invertible? Several answers may be correct.

Note: The value 1,2 below stands for the correlation coefficient of 1 and 2. The correlation coefficient is only defined if the variances of 1 and 2 are both positive.

1,2=0

1,2=1

(1)=0

1,2=−1

(1)=(2)

I know that if Var(R1)=0, then the covariance matrix is not invertible. However, should 1,2=0 indicate that the matrix is not invertible?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Please add the [tag:self-study] tag and read about it, as we have a particular way we handle such questions. In particular, what progress have you made with this homework assignment?

Comment: Perhaps the easiest way to address this question is to rely on the fact that when $S$ is a covariance matrix, it fails to be invertible if and only if there exists a nonzero vector $x$ for which $x^\prime S x = 0.$  This means some nonzero linear combination of the variables has zero variance.

Comment: To re-open this question, you need to provide some indication as to what you've already done on the problem.